How do I troubleshoot flickering power in certain outlets
My light and power are flickering on and off. I already checked the breaker box and everything looks fine. I flipped the switches and it continues to happen.

you are going to have to dig deeper, check for loose wires, also reset. the breakers, turn off and on

start by determining which breakers are affected

Also listen - you may hear the offending connection arcing. But yes, isolate which circuits, and shut them off (when not actively listening) until you can sort it out. There's a non-trivial risk of a fire starting, and the next troubleshooting step is to open up receptacle boxes and junction boxes looking for heat damage from loose connections - when you definitely want the power to be off.

If the outlets that are showing the problem are wired with stab type poke in wire terminations this could very well be the source. If so replace with new quality outlets that have screw terminals for securing the wires using either J-hooks on the wires or the screw clamp side connections found on some quality brand components.
